# Split text message in datagridview columns

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have made tcpserver listener with message receive. Message format is, for example: "acc123|472348923748989234".

I wanted to split by "|" in my columns of datagridview. First message shows ok but second after split returns following error: `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array`

Here is my code so far:

```
void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string _acc = textFromClient3 ;
    string[] txt = _acc.Split(new[] {'|'}, StringSplitOptions.None);

    for (int row = 0; row < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; row++)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value != null &&
            dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value.Equals(textFromClient))
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    DataGridViewRow addRow = new DataGridViewRow();

    addRow.CreateCells(dataGridView1);
    addRow.Cells[0].Value = textFromClient;
    addRow.Cells[1].Value = txt[0];
    addRow.Cells[2].Value = txt[1];

    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(addRow);
}
```

Where `textFromClient3` is the message, text[0] is "acc123" and text[1] should be "472348923748989234" from my example.

Comment: The error message leads me to believe that txt[1] is not being populated. Have you checked in debug mode to see if txt[1] = 472348923748989234 ?

Comment: Could you verify that `textFromClient3` is what you expect it to be? Also, are you getting that error from trying to access `txt[1]`, or from `Cells[2]`?

Comment: textFromClient3 is exactly what I expect and the error is from txt[1]. I tried txt[0] on Cells[2] and works. And if I use the entire textFromClient3, without split, in 1 cell it works too.

Comment: @snowYetis it dosent show in debug mode that.

Comment: Found Temporary solution. I set the collumn [2] to resizeble and to FILL . Now works but if the **texFromClient3** is clean it still return same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

```
if (txt.Length > 1 && txt[1] != null)
    {
        addRow.Cells[2].Value = txt[1];
    }
```

Thank you all for help.

Answer (score -1):

maybe i have same problem with you.
but the different is how to using multi line Message format

```
"acc123|472348923|XXXXX"
"acc123|472348923|gggggggg"
"acc123|472348923|kkkkkkkk"
```

maybe to use this coke

```
for (i=0; i <txt.Length; i++)
if (txt.Length > 1 && txt[i] != null)
    {
        addRow.Cells[i].Value = txt[i];
    }
```